# Very ample if and only if algebra generated in degree 1?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, line-bundles

Let $f: X \to S$ be a quasi-compact morphism of schemes and $\mathcal{L}$ an invertible $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Is it true that $\mathcal{L}$ is $f$-very ample if and only if $\mathcal{L}$ is $f$-ample and the $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$-graded commutative $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebra $\bigoplus_{m ∈ \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} f_* \mathcal{L}^{\otimes m}$ is generated over $\mathcal{O_S}$ in degree 1?

This is similar but not quite the same as the descriptions given in the [Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VR).

Comment: Not quite. If the algebra is generated in degree one ( and the line bundle is $f$-ample) it is very ample. Converse is not always true, even when the base is a point.

Comment: Interesting. If finiteness is an issue, what about the case where $f$ is proper and the base is Noetherian?

Comment: As I said, map could be proper and base is a point, but still may fail.

Comment: You did not mention properness. Having a very ample line bundle does not imply properness.

Could you write your counter-example as an answer?